# Set npm version when using maven versions:set goal

Tags: maven, npm, versioning

I am using Maven to build a multi-module Java application and deriving goals to also compile & test an Angular one. So far I could map the following goals: clean, generate-sources, compile, test.

Any ideas how to tell Maven to also set the package.json version when I execute the goal `mvn versions:set` ?

Comment: The `versions:set` goal is the [versions-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin) which does not support  `package.json`....

Comment: @khmarbaise I know this goal does not support package.json, I'd like to know if I can hook on this goal in order to trigger a custom execution like I do to clean folders (on mvn 'clean') or to trigger an npm run build (on mvn 'compile')